# How to calculate diameter across an image in Matlab?

Tags: matlab, image-processing, matrix

I have an image that I convert from a .mat file (size of .mat file is 406x512x380 double) below.

I need to calculate the diameter and it's change across the length of the image measured by the x-axis value (at each section -4, -2, 0, 2, 4 mm) what is the diameter? Here is my current code right now using imdistline() but clearly that is not the most effective when setting multiple locations.

[image]

```
%% pick frame of choice and run grid overlay %%
img = 40;
image = figure('Color', 'k');imagesc(X_1,Z_1,10*log10(R1_contrast(:,:,img)),[115 145]); colormap(gray); % setting colormap to gray
ax = gca;
%axis equal;
h=xlabel('Lateral (mm)'); %or h=get(gca,'xlabel')
set(h, 'FontSize', 16); 
set(h,'FontWeight','bold'); %bold font
z=ylabel('Depth (mm)');
set(z, 'FontSize', 16);
set(z, 'FontWeight', 'bold');
box(ax,'off'); 
set(gca, 'XColor', 'white'); % set x-axis color to white
set(gca, 'YColor', 'white');
set(gca, 'FontWeight', 'bold');
grid on;
axis image;
set(gca, 'GridColor','r', 'GridAlpha',1);
set(gca, 'Layer','top');
imdistline();
```

Comment: You could try and use an [edge detection algorithm](https://www.mathworks.com/discovery/edge-detection.html). Then, plot a profile at the desired x values and the distance between with peaks would give your the diameter. However, with the image that you have shown, a complete automation does seem like a challenge to me.

Comment: How would I plot the profile at the desired x values? Im not too familiar with that process but edge detection did seem to make it easier.

Comment: If your image is called say `im` simply get the pixel values at x-value `x` and plot it by something like `plot(im(x,:))` in its absolute simplest form. Google this, tones of examples are available. You could also use [`improfile`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/images/ref/improfile.html) to manually draw a line on your image or give coordinates to get the profile too.